# Max attribute not respected when manually entering value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `input` field for which I am trying to replicate hours in the day 0 - 24:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="24" step="1" value="00" class="time-hours">
<input type="number" min="0" max="60" step="1" value="00" class="time-seconds">
```

When I click on the up/down chevrons, the max, and min I can go to are 24 and 0 as set in my attributes.

However, if I click on a cell, I can enter any number, e.g. 100.

How can I ensure only numbers between 0 and 24 can be entered?

Comment: This can be done by using key events. As an option, you can use `<select>`

Comment: Don't worry about it - when the form is submitted, the browser will say "hang on a minute, this value is wrong" and require that the user enter a valid number in the box.

Comment: Use a dropdown construction instead.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - understood, however, from a UI/UX point of view, i would prefer the value not to be displayed.. or default to 24/the max?

Comment: @Tushar - not too keen on the UI/display of a drop down however

Comment: From a UX perspective, you should allow the user to type whatever they want. Only after they've typed should you say "this isn't right". A simple CSS solution might be `input:invalid {outline:2px solid red}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its a `form` submit, the browser will stop the user. But in case you really need the validation, you can do this:

```
$(".time-hours").keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val() > 24) {
    $(this).val("24");
  }
    if ($(this).val() < 0) {
    $(this).val("0");
  }
});

$(".time-seconds").keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val() > 60) {
    $(this).val("60");
  }
    if ($(this).val() < 0) {
    $(this).val("0");
  }
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/anoorally/bmzjpnjg/%5C)

Comment: You really should do `var $this = $(this);` or something, anything to avoid having to compute `$(this)`, constructing a new jQuery object THREE TIMES...

Comment: Its a quick solution, ofc it can always be optimized ;)

Comment: If it's so quick, why not optimise it in the first place? For instance, a more general function like `var $this = $(this), val = $this.val(), min = $this.attr("min"), max = $this.attr("max"); if( val < min) $this.val(min); else if( val > max) $this.val(max);` - then you don't have to redefine the same function if anything changes.

Comment: The thing about optimization is, you want to focus on optimizing the bottlenecks, not the parts that are already fast.  Constructing 100,000 new jQuery objects takes a grand total of 36 milliseconds.  (Really! I checked! https://jsfiddle.net/bko53wct/)  I think you can safely get away with doing it two extra times.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use javascript you can simple use this below code:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="24" step="1" value="00" class="time-hours" onblur="return minmax(this.value);">
<input type="number" min="0" max="60" step="1" value="00" class="time-seconds" onblur="return minmax(this.value);">

<script>
    function minmax(val){
        if(val > 24 || val < 0){
            alert("Value cannot be grater than 24 and min than 0");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

I have used onblur because whenever value changes in two boxes they will trigger a function and it will check textbox value if value is greater than 24 or min than 0 it will prompt an alert.

I have used alert you can use anything for your validations.

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform this pure JavaScript solution:

```
<script>
    ob = document.getElementById('f');
    ob.onblur = function(){

      if (ob.value*1 > ob.max*1 || ob.value*1 < ob.min*1){
        ob.value = 24
      }
    }
  </script>
```

Here you give the field an `id`. You are able to enclose it into a function to use it many fields.

Here is a [**demo**](http://jsbin.com/rohagoguwo/edit?html,output)